# Sql Server: How to create a db-snapshot from within stored procedure for non-privileged user?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, snapshot

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that creates a dB-snapshot for a non privileged user. 
The idea is to provide to a normal user a way to create a dB snapshot in order to run queries against it and delete the snapshot when it is done with it.

I thought it would be possible to use the 'with execute as owner" in the procedure declaration. However, I always get the following error:

```
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

Here is my code:

```
    -- The user that create the sp has sysadmin right
    CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[makeSnapshot] WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
    AS
        -- just an extract of the code (should test if exist...)
        DECLARE @exec NVARCHAR(2000)
        set @exec = 'CREATE DATABASE test_dbss1900 ON  ( NAME = test, FILENAME =   
                    ''C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL14.SQLSERVER2017\\MSSQL\\Data\\test_1900.ss'' )  AS SNAPSHOT OF test';  
        EXEC (@exec)
    GO

    -- try to execute it (with any user)
    EXEC dbo.[makeSnapshot]
```

Has anyone an idea how I can come up with a stored proc that will allow a normal user to create a db snapshot?

Thank for any help!

José

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution by looking at - http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#serverlevel (chapter 5.3)

The way was to use certificates